# ¿como bloquear acceso a archivos que contiene la carpeta con php y htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola quiza alguien me puede ayudar el caso es que quiero bloquear el acceso a las carpetas del servidor y archivos del backend que hacen funcionar al sitio. Entonces las carpetas eh logrado bloquearlas con el siguiente codigo:
`Options All -Indexes`
hasta ahi todo bien, pero si ingreso la ruta del archivo que contiene dicha carpeta en el buscador este se muestra. Entonces ¿como podría hacer para no permitir el acceso tanto a la carpeta como archivos?.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Apache usas?

Comment: segun el hosting 2.4.54

Comment: Prueba quitando `All`. Si el problema persiste añade a tu pregunta ejemplo de tu estructura de archivos/directorios, señalando la ubicación del .htaccess y el document root; ejemplifica la url que probaste y los resultados esperados y obtenidos. También te puede ayudar lo que aconseja [la documentación](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot).